# Validate email with RegEx following rules

Tags: javascript, regex

Needs to only contain `[a-zA-Z0-9.]`, and followed by an @ then the same match afterward, the match before, and after the @ shouldn't be any longer than 64 characters long, and at least one length.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+){1,64}@([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]){1,64}$
```

This seems to work but it sometimes takes forever, why is this?

Comment: define sometimes takes forever?

Comment: Can you provide some valid & invalid inputs.

Comment: *"then the same match afterward"* - So "abc@abc" would be valid, but "abc@aaa" would not? (I don't really think that's what you *meant,* but it's what you *said.*) Why does the part to the left of the "@" have both a `+` *and* `{1,64}`? That allows any number of characters. Remove the `+`, and if you just want to test "does it match" you can remove all of the parentheses.

Comment: `^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]{1,64})@(\1)$` Like this?

Comment: Sometime it is getting hanged. It is  taking long time. If we try same thing again then it works.

Comment: Thanks guys, removing the + fixed it for me, that was my only issue!

Comment: @Coldspeed is there a way to use the reference to group 1 like you have with (\1) so I don't have to duplicate the whole group again? aaa@aaa.com should return true, but currently with your example it only matches if aaa@aaa is the string. `^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]{1,64})@([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]{1,64})$` just seems like alot of duplication for no real reason

Comment: The thing is, without using the reference, I have no idea how you can enforce equality between the first and second part of the text.

Comment: The text of your question says `[a-zA-Z0-9.]`, but the code you give includes a hyphen. Also, please note there's no need to escape a period inside a charcter set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have the `+` operator in the first part of the regex. I hope this could be useful for you

`^([a-zA-Z\d\.]{1,64})@([a-zA-Z\d\.]{1,64})$`

Answer (score 0):

For email regex you should use http://emailregex.com/ which provides this regex

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

also, if you can you should usually just use

```
<input type="email">
```

Comment: You've just copied this from another solution, this does not meet my requirements.